# Stops to read the remained elements after reads two same elements (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, arrays

for example, when I run this code,

```
int test[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Android Studio only shows two of its elements

```
0 0
```

But when I run this,

```
int test[] = {0, 1, 0, 1};
```

it shows

```
0 1 0 1
```

I need to get all of elements of the array
But Java (Eclipse) prints what I wanted, it prints all of its elements
It looks like it stops to read when two elements are same
I tried arrays with integers, booleans, and used HashMap and results were same
Arrays were declared in MainActivity and were read in onCreate
Here's the code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int test[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            Log.v( "HELLO", Integer.toString( test[ i ] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: Sorry for late, test is the array's name

Comment: @Reltpid please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio sometime skips similar logs with message like **your output and 3 similar messages**. Also if there is not sufficient memmory to write logs it might be skipping those posts. Try putting some delay between your message and check if it still behaves in similar manner. also try filtering by log tag and check the output as it will give you better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your below OUTPUT

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int test[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            Log.e("Array Value Pos "+ i, Integer.toString(test[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]